# is there a way to search the twitter API by someones email address?

Tags: twitter

I see sites like http://klout.com where you add a bunch of emails and they tell you what services a person uses and rates the persons usages. I have a list of emails for a new site and I'd like to see who is a twitter user or not in my admin panel by calling the twitter API. However, I can't seem to find any documentation on how to search for a twitter user by their email address. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No. This functionality was offered at one point, but was abused by spammers and was removed.

Long answer: [Twitter API: search people by email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931657/twitter-api-search-people-by-email)