# getting twitter user through email

Tags: twitter

is it possible, using the twitter api, to get a twitter user through his email - searching for user by email?
i know that the user/show method was able to do it, but now the email parameter has been deprecated.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this via the Twitter API, unless you're in the closed beta for this feature, sorry.

Prior art:

[How do I get a Twitter username based on an email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5995944/210774)
[Retrieve email from twitter profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4889029/210774)
[Twitter API: search people by email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3931657/210774)
[Any way to get Twitter user email?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3372797/210774)