# Retrieve email from twitter profile

Tags: php, rest, twitter, oauth

Huh, after some searches on the net on how to retrieve user email address, the short answer is - there is no way.

But, is there really no way of fetching user email? A hacky one or something?

It's not meant for spamming or stuff like that, but, my application local user storage uses email as it's core ID, and I have to compare if that particular twitter account is already registered in database or not. I'm using this technique for facebook authentication and it works flawlessly, but client demands twitter login too, but I have no idea how could I compare it without looking at emails.

P.S. I hope I've made myself clear enough, if not, don't hesitate to ask, this is actually pretty important at the moment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "A hacky way of getting user e-mails, but it's legit, really man, honest"? Sounds fishy - it's my understanding that e-mails aren't provided __exactly__ for this reason. Anyway, are you absolutely, completely, 100% sure that you aren't getting back any sort of unique ID that you could use instead of the e-mail address? (Similarly, FB login gives you back the user's FB id number, amongst other things) You could then form it into something resembling an e-mail (e.g. `123456789@twitter.invalid`), if your app insists that the ID must be in e-mail format.

Comment: @Piskvor: Well, you've got my idea wrong, but since question is answered, I'll skip the explaining part for what I need it for. Thanks for your interest and idea anyways!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely no way at all. It is not in the API, it is not on any pages to be scraped. The email appears nowhere on Twitter and cannot be obtained from Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

We can create twtter account with out email, so in api's twitter will not provide the email of its users, as a user is not necessarily a human.

to get the friends list please use api :
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friends/list