# How do I get a Twitter username based on an email address?

Tags: twitter, email-analytics

Is there an API (probably provided by Twitter but not necessarily) that will give me the Twitter username for each email address I give it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723192/is-there-a-way-to-search-the-twitter-api-by-someones-email-address

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Official response from Twitter on this issue is here - http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=353

"This API method is offered in a closed beta at this time, and we are not accepting new partners. However, we're working on the long-term strategy for this method and will keep you in mind when we decide to open it up again. I am sorry for the inconvenience this may cause in the meantime, and please let me know if you have any other questions."

Comment: Great answer. Another note in that thread mentions that facebook allow it, which is great because I only want access to get some kind of gauge on how 'social' a person is. Just out of interest: How fair is it to assume that if someone has many facebook friends, they also follow many twitter users? I've seen no data on this.

Comment: I wouldn't say so, actually.  In my experience, people who are heavy Twitter users are generally heavy Facebook users as well, but not so much the other way around.  With that in mind, Facebook friends will be a better indicator of how social than # of twitter users they follow.  Plenty of people follow lots of people in hopes they will get a follow back, so you'll see inflated numbers overall there.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, the Twitter API doesn't expose or otherwise give access to the email address.

I understand your needs, as I also wish this were available, but I believe this is the decision Twitter went with.