# How do I get facebook username based on email address?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, email-analytics

Title sums it up. Almost identical to my recent twitter question at [How do I get a Twitter username based on an email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995944/how-do-i-get-twitter-username-based-on-email-address).

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=[EMAIL ADDRESS]&type=user&access_token=[APITOKEN]`

You can actually get the API token by going to [Facebook developer documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and clicking on the friends link. The token is in the url.